# excel import using c#

Tags: c#, office-interop

i am working on excel import to grid view using DataTable in c#, but my problem is its working fine on my local system but its redirecting to login page on my online server and i have tried both Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel & OLEdb connection. but the problem is same. please tell me what is the problem with these or any one have any other function to import Excel data in GridView.

```
private void processExcel(string filename)
{
    filename = Server.MapPath("~/Files/WM-0b23-productsBook.xlsx");
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;

    var missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, false, true, missing, missing, missing, true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, '\t', false, false, 0, false, true, 0);
    xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
    Array myValues = (Array)xlRange.Cells.Value2;

    int vertical = myValues.GetLength(0);
    int horizontal = myValues.GetLength(1);

    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

    // must start with index = 1
    // get header information
    for (int i = 1; i <= horizontal; i++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(myValues.GetValue(1, i).ToString()));
    }

    // Get the row information
    for (int a = 2; a <= vertical; a++)
    {
        object[] poop = new object[horizontal];
        for (int b = 1; b <= horizontal; b++)
        {
            poop[b - 1] = myValues.GetValue(a, b);
        }
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row.ItemArray = poop;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    // assign table to default data grid view
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    xlWorkBook.Close(true, missing, missing);
    xlApp.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlApp);
}

private void releaseObject(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        obj = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj = null;
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Comment: You might need MS office Package Called DataBase Engine. 2007 Version Worked for me.
Hope this Will help you

Answer (score 1):

Have a look:

```
private void processExcel(string filename)
    {
        filename = Server.MapPath("~/Files/WM-0b23-productsBook.xlsx");
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    var missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename, false, true, missing, missing, missing, true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, '\t', false, false, 0, false, true, 0);
    xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorkSheet.UsedRange;
    Array myValues = (Array)xlRange.Cells.Value2;

    int vertical = myValues.GetLength(0);
    int horizontal = myValues.GetLength(1);

    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

    // must start with index = 1
    // get header information
    for (int i = 1; i <= horizontal; i++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(myValues.GetValue(1, i).ToString()));
    }

    // Get the row information
    for (int a = 2; a <= vertical; a++)
    {
        object[] poop = new object[horizontal];
        for (int b = 1; b <= horizontal; b++)
        {
            poop[b - 1] = myValues.GetValue(a, b);
        }
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        row.ItemArray = poop;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    // assign table to default data grid view
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    xlWorkBook.Close(true, missing, missing);
    xlApp.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlApp);
}

private void releaseObject(object obj)
{
    try
    {
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(obj);
        obj = null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        obj = null;
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to release the Object " + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me on this. it worked for me. great efforts

Answer (score 0):

It is better not using MS Office interop in server cases which will bring a lot of performance and memory issues in the future. Recommend using some 3rd party library, for example: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Spread.Services/  to get what you wanted.